# Transforming action name in route declaration

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm wondering if there is a way to declare routes in MVC3 so that the route "zone1/{controller}/{action}" would direct to `{controller}.zone1{action}` method and "zone2/{controller}/{action}" would direct to `{controller}.zone2{action}` method, for example. So that's basically transforming the target action name based on the route.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out The Attribute Routing project. You can specify on your methods the routes which I feel is a bit easier to read. Here's a decent blurb on it:
http://gregorsuttie.com/2012/01/12/attributerouting-for-mvc/

You could also write your own custom route handler but I don't believe you can do what you want without some custom code. I could be wrong here though. The attribute routing project should work just fine for what you want however.

Comment: That's a very useful library, thanks for the hint. I tried to apply it to my case, but it looks like it requires the controller to have a parameterless constructor, whereas I'm using constructor parameters to inject some service dependencies... I went through the doc and couldn't find anything related, maybe you know more ?

Comment: Oops, wrong configuration on my side, it's all working now, thanks again.